# How do I get the current username in .NET using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I get the current username in .NET using C#?

Comment: In the context of impersonation the username can be different than the logged in user session username (eg runas or .Net impersonation in managed code) see others' comments below

Answer (score 1054, accepted):

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: How is this different than `Environment.UserName`?

Comment: This question is already discussed in this link ...... may be repeated question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218778/how-to-get-currently-logged-username-from-windows-service-in-net

Comment: Resharper states `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` can return null. This seems to be a false positive, according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998381/can-windowsidentity-getcurrent-return-null)

Comment: @SimonGillbee, this is wrong, `Environment.UserName` will return "RunAs" user.

Comment: To verify.... `MessageBox.Show(Environment.UserName);` put this in your `window_loaded` event, and run it using RunAs....

Comment: [Discussed on META](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228096/misleading-comments-with-high-volume-of-upvotes)

Comment: This returns `Domain\Username`. How can I get the Name associated with the username?

Comment: I'm confused, what's the real difference between the 2 methods? Is it just the `NetworkName\` prefix? Do both methods return the user the application is running as?

Comment: @SimonGillbee: Can you provide an actual example of a case where they differ other than (that one gives the domain name)? Per [Bolu's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c#comment34794502_1240379)? I, too, have verified that if I (say) schedule a task to run as a different user, both calls return that user, not the logged-in user.

Comment: My website is using IIS but when I visit the page from another computer within the network, I keep seeing "Network Service" as the username. I tried all different option but it doesn't give me the logged in user who is viewing the page. Any idea?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I extracted just the username by using `Split()` like so: `string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];`

Comment: this for some reason is returning `<my_username>/<my_username>` like `mrid/mrid`

Comment: this gives the full / qualified windows username i.e. includes domain name (if on one).

Comment: I used this and in server, it returns me the name of service/api instead of logged in user because currently in API I have turned on anonymous authentication.

Comment: @SamHarwell One consideration, is whether you are writing for Windows only, or for another OS.

Answer (score 385):

If you are in a network of users, then the username will be different:

```
Environment.UserName
- Will Display format : 'Username'
```

rather than

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
- Will Display format : 'NetworkName\Username'
```

Choose the format you want.

Comment: You can use `Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName` to get seemingly the same result as `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`. Now, what's the difference, you ask...I am not sure.

Comment: I needed to get the user running the app rather than who is logged in (Environment.UserName isn't what I want), so I did the following to strip off the domain:  `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split( '\\' ).Last();`

Comment: You need to add `ToArray()` after `Split` before calling `Last()`

Comment: @codenamezero No `ToArray()` is needed.  You would need `using System.Linq;` though.

Comment: Or without using Linq: `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split( '\\' )[1];`.

Comment: These are two totally different things. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() will return the user running the process. Environment.UserName might return the logged in user (but it doesn't always for some reason)

Comment: Environment.UserName will return 'root' in docker hosted in linux

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240379/109941

Answer (score 126):

Try the property: [`Environment.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx).

Comment: Or, `string userName = Environment.UserName;`

Comment: Caution: like Simon Gillbee mentioned in the comments of the accepted answer, `Environment.UsernName` gives the logged-in account-name, but `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` is returning the account-name that the application is running as.

Comment: @leo: Caution: That information is also apparently incorrect, see [Bolu's reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c#comment34794502_1240379). :-)

Comment: DO NOT use it with ASP.NET.
learn.microsoft.com says: "If an ASP.NET application runs in a development environment, the UserName property returns the name of the current user. In a published ASP.NET application, this property returns the name of the application pool account (such as Default AppPool)."

Comment: @feihoa MS worded that poorly and made it sound like the property is somehow doing different things depending on which environment it runs in. It doesn't. They should have made it more clear that it (always) returns the user that executes the server-side process, i.e. what is visible in Task Manager on the server.

Comment: @OskarBerggren: If it makes you feel any better I had to explain to another developer that calling MsgBox from the web server process would not in fact display a message to the user.

Answer (score 35):

The documentation for Environment.UserName seems to be a bit conflicting:

*[Environment.UserName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)*

On the same page it says:

> Gets the user name of the person who is currently logged on to the Windows operating system.

AND

> displays the user name of the person who started the current thread

If you test Environment.UserName using RunAs, it will give you the RunAs user account name, not the user originally logged on to Windows.

Answer (score 26):

I totally second the other answers, but I would like to highlight one more method which says

```
String UserName = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

The above method returned me the username in the format: **DomainName\UserName**. For example, EUROPE\UserName

Which is different from:

```
String UserName = Environment.UserName;
```

Which displayed in the format: **UserName**

And finally:

```
String UserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

which gave: `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR` (while running the application on IIS server) and `DomainName\UserName` (while running the application on a local server).

Comment: What namespace is required to use the "Request."?

Comment: @TK-421 `Request` only works if you are a web application. It's an instance of `System.Web.HttpRequest`

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli - Thanks for your comment, yes Request would only work if you are using a web application.

Comment: Any answer that just throws a type name at you without mentioning AT THE VERY LEAST the namespace (not to mention the full name of the assembly) should really be downvoted.  Unfortunately, if we were to be doing this, we would have to be downvoting 99% of all C# answers.  Oh, humans.

Answer (score 23):

Use:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

That will be the logon name.

Answer (score 17):

```
String myUserName = Environment.UserName
```

This will give you output - **your_user_name**

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240379/109941

Answer (score 16):

Just in case someone is looking for user ***Display Name*** as opposed to ***User Name***, like me.

Here's the treat :

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName

Add Reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in your project.

Answer (score 12):

You may also want to try using:

```
Environment.UserName;
```

Like this...:

```
string j = "Your WindowsXP Account Name is: " + Environment.UserName;
```

Hope this has been helpful.

Answer (score 12):

I tried several combinations from existing answers, but they were giving me

```
DefaultAppPool
IIS APPPOOL
IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
```

I ended up using

```
string vUserName = User.Identity.Name;
```

Which gave me the actual users domain username only.

Comment: Excellent. I also received the app pool identity only. But your code resolved my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: It sounds like you wanted the username of the user making a request, I guess to an MVC or Web API controller. That's different to the username the process is running under

Comment: @BenAaronson The question doesn't say anything about what username is running a process.  I needed the currently logged in domain username and a search brought me to this page, this code ended up giving me what I needed.

Answer (score 10):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName` for the actually logged in user as     `Environment.UserName` still returns the account being used by the current process.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, also see: System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserDomainName

Comment: It all depends on your definition of "the current user".

Answer (score 10):

I've tried all the previous answers and found the answer on MSDN after none of these worked for me. See 'UserName4' for the correct one for me.

I'm after the *Logged in User*, as displayed by:

```
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
```

Here's a little function I wrote to try them all. My result is in the comments after each row.

```
protected string GetLoggedInUsername()
{
    string UserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; // Gives NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
    String UserName2 = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name; // Gives NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
    String UserName3 = Environment.UserName; // Gives SYSTEM
    string UserName4 = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; // Gives actual user logged on (as seen in <ASP:Login />)
    string UserName5 = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName; // Gives SYSTEM
    return UserName4;
}
```

Calling this function returns the logged in username by return.

Update: I would like to point out that running this code on my Local server instance shows me that Username4 returns "" (an empty string), but UserName3 and UserName5 return the logged in User. Just something to beware of.

Comment: My website is using IIS but when I visit the page from another computer within the network, I keep seeing "Network Service" as the username. I tried all different option but it doesn't give me the logged in user who is viewing the page. Any idea?

Comment: NOTE: It's not made clear, but the above example applies in the context of a web application running in IIS, where several of them will display the name of the server windows account that executes the ASP.Net application pool. If running as a interactive program or windows service, the one from HttpContext will be unavailable, and one of the others should be used to find the account under which the process executes.

Comment: Also note that UserName2, Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name, will always give a WindowsIdentity, but it will be the remote user if authenticated using NTLM, otherwise (unauthenticated, or Forms authentication), it will be the local user that executes the process (e.g. application pool account).

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

now it looks better

Comment: Thanks for this example. Note that this is different from the above answers, but exactly what I was looking for. This code returns the logged user EVEN IF THE PROCESS WAS ELEVATED and now runs in admin name. I needed this for my Setup.exe. If I run the Setup.exe on a non-user account the Windows Installer asks for the password of an administrator account. Then the setup runs in the username of the admin. 'Environment.UserName' as well as 'System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName' as well as 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name' return the admin user but not this.

Comment: Just be aware that in case of no logged in user this code will produce an exception

Comment: BE CAREFUL - This answer uses Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI), which is the infrastructure for managing Windows-based operating systems. I used this in our app, and we got a number of failures in the field, caused either by users having a corrupt WMI database on their machine, or the WMI service not running at all. There are usually less-expensive, more reliable ways to do things if you're already running on the local machine.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code (but not in C#):

```
Private m_CurUser As String

Public ReadOnly Property CurrentUser As String
    Get
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_CurUser) Then
            Dim who As System.Security.Principal.IIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()

            If who Is Nothing Then
                m_CurUser = Environment.UserDomainName & "\" & Environment.UserName
            Else
                m_CurUser = who.Name
            End If
        End If
        Return m_CurUser
    End Get
End Property
```

Here is the code (now also in C#):

```
private string m_CurUser;

public string CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_CurUser))
        {
            var who = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            if (who == null)
                m_CurUser = System.Environment.UserDomainName + @"\" + System.Environment.UserName;
            else
                m_CurUser = who.Name;
        }
        return m_CurUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose to be answer in C#

Answer (score 4):

For a Windows Forms app that was to be distributed to several users, many of which log in over vpn, I had tried several ways which all worked for my local machine testing but not for others. I came across a Microsoft article that I adapted and works.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ManageExclusion
{
    public static class UserIdentity

    {
        // concept borrowed from 
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx

        public static string GetUser()
        {
            IntPtr accountToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;
            WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(accountToken);
            return windowsIdentity.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I went over most of the answers here and none of them gave me the right user name.

In my case I wanted to get the logged in user name, while running my app from a different user, like when shift+right click on a file and "Run as a different user".

The answers I tried gave me the 'other' username.

This blog post supplies a way to get the logged in user name, which works even in my scenario:
https://smbadiwe.github.io/post/track-activities-windows-service/

It uses Wtsapi

Edit: the essential code from the blog post, in case it ever disappears, is

> Add this code to a class inheriting from ServiceBase

```
[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
private static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WtsInfoClass wtsInfoClass, out IntPtr ppBuffer, out int pBytesReturned);
[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
private static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pointer);
 
private enum WtsInfoClass
{
    WTSUserName = 5, 
    WTSDomainName = 7,
}
 
private static string GetUsername(int sessionId, bool prependDomain = true)
{
    IntPtr buffer;
    int strLen;
    string username = "SYSTEM";
    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, WtsInfoClass.WTSUserName, out buffer, out strLen) && strLen > 1)
    {
        username = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
        WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
        if (prependDomain)
        {
            if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, WtsInfoClass.WTSDomainName, out buffer, out strLen) && strLen > 1)
            {
                username = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer) + "\\" + username;
                WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
    return username;
}
```

> If you don't have one already, add a constructor to the class; and add this line to it:

```
CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
```

EDIT:
Per comments requests, here's how I get the session ID - which is the active console session ID:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

var activeSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
if (activeSessionId == INVALID_SESSION_ID) //failed
{
    logger.WriteLog("No session attached to console!");    
}
```

Comment: Always copy external content into your answer rather than just putting a link. If the link dies your answer is useless

Comment: Interesting approach. How do you get the session ID though?

Comment: @Lopsided edited my answer per your request

Comment: This route is not reliable. Depending on where the app is. If it runs in a secure network, like a hospital, odds are this will fail. I've seen it happen in a terminal environment before. The accepted answer works just fine.

Comment: Ok, but fact is that for my use case, which is described in the answer I posted, the accepted answer does not work, and my answer does.

Comment: Your sharing is very helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the current Windows username:

```
using System;

class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        //  <-- Keep this information secure! -->
        Console.WriteLine("UserName: {0}", Environment.UserName);
    }
}
```

Comment: My website is using IIS but when I visit the page from another computer within the network, I keep seeing "Network Service" as the username. I tried all different option but it doesn't give me the logged in user who is viewing the page. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

In case it's helpful to others, when I upgraded an app from c#.net 3.5 app to Visual Studio 2017 this line of code `User.Identity.Name.Substring(4);` threw this error "*startIndex cannot be larger than length of string*" (it didn't baulk before).

It was happy when I changed it to `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` however I ended up using `Environment.UserName;` to get the logged in Windows user and without the domain portion.

Comment: I've flagged this as "not an answer" because it starts off talking about a completely unrelated exception caused by you blindly trying to substring(4) a string that clearly doesn't have at least 4 characters in it, which is nothing to do with the question, and then only mentions solutions that have already been mentioned many times before in other answers. This answer is just noise and should be deleted