# How does it happen Azure web role entry point and .aspx page handler are run in different processes?

Tags: windows, iis, deployment, azure, cloud

I'm playing with [this Azure web role sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg433178). It contains a class derived from `RoleEntryPoint` and a .aspx page that contains a button click handler.

I test it in Azure Emulator. I put the following code (taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-to-get-current-username-in-net-using-c/1240379#1240379))

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

in both role `OnStart()` and the button click handler. When role `OnStart()` is invoked it happens to run in `WaIISHost.exe` under `MachineName\\MyLogin` account and when button handler code is invoked it happens to run in `w3wp.exe` under `MachineName\\NETWORK SERVICE` account. That's surprising.

Why are these pieces of code from the same role project run inside different processes and under different accounts? Can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David is correct. In addition to that, you can turn off this behavior and run everything in the hostable web core (as it worked before SDK 1.4). You just need to comment out the "Sites" section in the services definition like in the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="aExpense.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="aExpense" vmsize="Medium">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="DataConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="allowInsecureRemoteEndpoints" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
```

Answer (score 3):

With Windows Azure v1.3 and beyond, a Web Role takes advantage of the full IIS, rather than Hosted Web Core. IIS runs in a separate appdomain.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx) from the Windows Azure team for the gory details.

Comment: David is correct. You can, if you want, run on Hosted Web Core only (no IIS) if you comment out the "<Sites>" section on your service definition file.

Comment: @Eugenio Pace: Could you please add that as a separate answer? That's very important and completely inobvious that Full IIS can be turned off so easily.