# Why can't i access the RoleEnvironment in Application_Start when using a RoleEntryPoint?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-diagnostics

I have a Azure WebRole which I'm trying to configure logging for using the DiagnosticMonitor.

According to the documentation at windowsazure.com the logging should be implemented in OnStart:

> ```
> Note: The code in the following steps is typically added to the OnStart method of the role.
> ```

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/

In order to access the OnStart method I have to define a RoleEntryPoint. But once it is defined I can't access the RoleEnvironment in web applications Application_Start.

How can I make the RoleEnvironment available to the application while still being able to use the DiagnosticMonitor?

I store the applications connection-strings in the service configuration.

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {

        public override bool OnStart()
        {


            // config
            var config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

            LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyCustomLogs");

            DirectoryConfiguration dirConfig = new DirectoryConfiguration();
            dirConfig.Container = "wad-mycustomlogs-container";
            dirConfig.DirectoryQuotaInMB = localResource.MaximumSizeInMegabytes;
            dirConfig.Path = localResource.RootPath;


            DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagMonitorConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
            diagMonitorConfig.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);
            diagMonitorConfig.Directories.DataSources.Add(dirConfig);

            DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);



            return base.OnStart();
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you try and access the RoleEnvironment in web applications Application_Start?

Comment: It seems to have something to do with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6202411/348841 but can someone please explain how I should do?

Comment: Are you trying to (re)configure your DiagnosticsMonitor from Application_Start?

Comment: @SteveWilkes It throws an error. I've checked the RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable and it's false. If i exclude the RoleEntryPoint it's true.

Comment: @JonasStensved we have lots of projects in that configuration .. do you have sites configured in your csdef?

Comment: @Simon No, I'm trying to just get it running and persist my application logs.

Comment: @Simon, Yes I have the sites-element. I think it was added by default by Visual Studio.

Comment: and running the project works in the emulator?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9470/discussion-between-simon-and-jonas-stensved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it.

After cleaning my solution, rebuilding, restarting IIS, shutting down the azure emulators and restarting Visual Studio it suddenly started working.

I changed no code at all.

(I even did all of those things before posting as well but it only worked when I did it all at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

This is defintely the right example set of code. You need to set all of this in the Role though NOT in your web application.

NOTE: since Azure now has full IIS the context is different between the RoleEntryPoint On_start and the Web application, which is running in it's own worker pool within IIS.

Just a quick sanity checklist:

- The code you're writing is in your class that inherits from RoleEntryPoint (typically WebRole.cs NOT in the Global.asax)?
- You're running the project in the Azure Emulator (not inadvertently starting a web project directly?)

If you're running the application in the Azure emulator or deployed to Azure itself RoleEnvironment is available from within your IIS application as long as you have the relevant DLLs reference. If you can build with RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable in your code, then the libraries are included. The only thing I can think is that you're running the web site directly, not within the Azure emulator.

Set the Cloud project to be your startup in Visual Studio and you should be golden.

Comment: Yes on both questions. class WebRole inherits RoleEntryPoint and I'm using the Emulator. If I just exclude the WebRole.cs from my project I can access the RoleEnvironment from the application again.