# How can I retrieve Logged In user in an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using windows authentication in a ASP.Net Web Application and in the code-behind attempting to retrieve the logged in user name.  I am using this routine WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name but instead of getting the name of the user, I am getting - NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.  What do I need to change or are my users logging in a different way than expected?

Comment: Is anonymous access still open?

Comment: check this http://forums.asp.net/t/1102996.aspx

Comment: I think this question may contain the answer you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-to-get-current-username-in-net-using-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
</system.web>
```

This will make your web app impersonate the currently logged in user. That does have some implications. An important one is that the **logged in user** must have the proper rights to files, folders, databases and so on.

If you don't want that, you can use `User.Identity` instead of `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`.

Comment: `impersonate` is not needed. No matter what value is given to it, `Page.User.Identity` remains the same.  `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` returns application pool identity.

Answer (score 3):

Use `this.Context.User.Identity.Name`, which will get the identity for the current HTTPContext object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

Comment: to add to James answer, the WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() is returning the user running the application pool, not the user logged into your app