# How to get logged in PC username in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

like in this thread [How do I get the current username in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c)

but the code

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

doesn't seem to work on Windows 8 apps.

How can I do that?

Comment: read this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/retrieve-user-information-in-windows-store-apps-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: question answered.. thanks man

Answer (score 5):

Step 1:

> Create a Blank Windows Store Application using C# and XAML language.

Step 2:

```
    x:Class="SetAccountPicture.UserProfileInformation"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:local="using:SetAccountPicture"

    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    mc:Ignorable="d">



    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid Height="500" Width="1000">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>

                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="Get_UserInformation" Click="Get_UserInformation_Click_1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="60" Width="250" Content="Get User Information" FontSize="20"></Button>

            <TextBlock Text="User's Display Name is: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Text="User First Name is: " Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Text="User Last Name is: " Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

            <TextBlock Text="Account Picture is: " Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

            <TextBlock x:Name="UserName" Text="User Name is: " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

            <TextBlock x:Name="FistName" Text="First Name is: " Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

            <TextBlock x:Name="LastName" Text="Last Name is: " Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>

            <Image  x:Name="AccountPicture" Height="150" Width="200" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Stretch="Fill"></Image>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

Step 3:

```
using Windows.Storage;

using Windows.Storage.Pickers;

using Windows.Storage.Streams;

using Windows.System.UserProfile;

using Windows.UI.Core;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
```

Step 4:

```
string displayName = await UserInformation.GetDisplayNameAsync();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))

{

     rootPage.NotifyUser("No Display Name was returned", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

}
else

{

    UserName.Text = displayName;

}
```

Get the first Name for the current User.

Note: This is only aviablable for Microsoft Accounts.

```
string firstName = await UserInformation.GetFirstNameAsync();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
{

     rootPage.NotifyUser("No Display Name was returned", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

}

else

{

   FistName.Text = firstName;

}
```

Get the last Name for the current user; see:

```
string lastName = await UserInformation.GetLastNameAsync();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))

{

    rootPage.NotifyUser("No Display Name was returned", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

}

else

{

    LastName.Text = lastName;

}
```

Get the Account Picture for the current user.

Note: You can request three types of images. For Example: Small, large and video(dynamic image). If available it returns.

```
StorageFile image = UserInformation.GetAccountPicture(AccountPictureKind.SmallImage) as StorageFile;


if (image != null)

{

       rootPage.NotifyUser("SmallImage path = " + image.Path, NotifyType.StatusMessage);

     try

    {

         IRandomAccessStream imageStream = await image.OpenReadAsync();

         BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

         bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);

         AccountPicture.Source = bitmapImage;                 

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

         rootPage.NotifyUser("Error opening stream: " + ex.ToString(), NotifyType.ErrorMessage);

    }

 }
else

{

      rootPage.NotifyUser("Small Account Picture is not available", NotifyType.StatusMessage);              

}
```

[image: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/retrieve-user-information-in-windows-store-apps-using-C-Sharp/]

[The Picture and Source code:](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/retrieve-user-information-in-windows-store-apps-using-C-Sharp/)