# How to show current user's name?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a textblock that says "Welcome username".

username = current Windows user.

I'm working in a WPF project.

Comment: Bug report: Why does it say `Welcome HP User` or `Welcome Valued Customer` in your app?

Comment: The machine simply doesn't know the *correct* way to address the user.  User account names are too frequently abbreviated and do not give you enough info to know whether a title is needed or the user finds it acceptable to be addressed by a machine with their first name.  People are sticklers for details like that.  You'd have to contact the domain controller to have a half-decent shot at it.  System.DirectoryServices namespace.  Given the risk of ticking off your user it is certainly best to just not do this.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `Environment.UserName` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx)):

> Gets the user name of the person who is currently logged on to the
>   Windows operating system.

*Example:*

```
Console.WriteLine("UserName: {0}", Environment.UserName);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the user who is currently running the process, use:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

OR

```
string userName = System.Environment.UserName
```

But the user you get from `Environment.UserName` is not guaranteed to be the user running the current process.

The difference between the two is explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c#comment9869078_1240379):

> The reason to prefer `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` is that this returns
>   the account that the application is running as. This is not
>   necessarily the account that is currently logged into Windows (think
>   "RunAs" or impersonation/delegation). So, if you want to know the
>   logged-in user, use the Environment (if you trust it). If you want to
>   know the security context your application is running as, using
>   `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`.