# Getting %userprofile% from registry using .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, registry

How can I get %userprofile% path from the registry using .NET 3.5?

I can get the `Users` directory from `..\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`, but that does not give me the username. If I can somehow get the username then I can combine that with the info in `ProfileList`

I am on Windows 8.

Comment: If you want the user name have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c