# Finding user name of current logged in user using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm trying to get the user name of the current user. When I log in as `Johnny Smith` and run my application without administrator privileges it will return me the correct user name, `Johnny Smith`. But the problem is that when I right click and choose "Run as Administrator", Windows will prompt me with a login screen for the administrator and after login my application returns user name `admin`, not the user which is logged in currently.

I have tried:

```
strUserLabel.Text = Environment.UserName
```

Also

```
Dim WSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim strUser = ""

While strUser = ""
    strUser = WSHNetwork.Username
End While

strUserLabel.Text = strUser
```

Both return me the administrator user name when prompted as administrator.

Comment: ok but I want to remain username of user not of admin.

Comment: `strUserLabel.Text = Environment.UserName` this should work because am using it many forms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14518508/1271037

Comment: @MarioLIPCIK try `strUserLabel.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` and comment what you are getting

Comment: @MarioLIPCIK `strUserLabel.Text =System.Environment.UserName`

Comment: @hector `strUserLabel.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returned me 'NetworkName\Username' and `strUserLabel.Text = Environment.UserName` returned just user name but it still was changing befor when I ran it as Admin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured it out. I used this function which will determine which process which the user is using. In my code I defined that look for username of the `explorer.exe` process.

```
Function GetUserName() As String

    Dim selectQuery As Management.SelectQuery = New Management.SelectQuery("Win32_Process")
    Dim searcher As Management.ManagementObjectSearcher = New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(selectQuery)
    Dim y As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection
    y = searcher.Get

    For Each proc As Management.ManagementObject In y
        Dim s(1) As String
        proc.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", CType(s, Object()))
        Dim n As String = proc("Name").ToString()
        If n = "explorer.exe" Then
            Return s(0)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**Index** of **0** will return **username**

**Index** of **1** will return **domain name** of user

Comment: What is the minimum version of .NET Framework required for this?

Comment: Take too long to execute

Answer (score 12):

In the MSDN documentation, I discovered they changed the definition of property `Environment.UserName`.

[Before .NET 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Gets the user name of the person who started the current thread.

[Starting from version 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Gets the user name of the person who is currently logged on to the Windows operating system

Comment: i think @Mario LIPCIK should store his `user` to a `string` before  `run as admin` for his application so that he can get the actual user from the stored variable

Comment: @hector - you can't do that. If you right click and run as admin then the whole process is elevated from the start and is running under a different user

Comment: @hector yes my aplication works like that now, but I have several scripts in it which requre admin rights... so when I run my script wil will ask me for every single script to enter password. That is the reason I need my application to run as admin but get corent logged on user

Answer (score 7):

I think the accepted answer above is a VERY resource intensive way to find a username. It has nested loops with hundreds of items. In my 8GP RAM PC this takes 2+ seconds!

How about:

- Username: `SystemInformation.Username`, and
- DomainName: `Environment.UserDomainName`

Tested in VS2017

Answer (score 0):

`SystemInformation.Username` doesn't work for certain applications. In my case, code is being run as System but explorer.exe is being run as Daniel. `SystemInformation.Username` reports System.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your asnawer

Answer (score 0):

if using Identity
Dim UserEmail As String = Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you Imports System then you can use Environment.UserName