# How to add a users name to path in C#?

Tags: c#, directory

Hello stackoverflow community, I want to know how I would be able to do this code: `Directory.Delete(@"C:\NAME\AppData\Local", true);`But where it says "NAME" I want to get the username of the computer, is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: If you mean `C:\USERS\NAME\AppData\Local` then `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking for a way to replace "NAME" with current user logged on that computer. If so then you can use [`Environment.UserName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username(v=vs.110).aspx). `Environment.UserName` will return you the user on the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,
[Getting the computer name in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c)

and

`string directory = "C:\"+username+"\AppData\Local";
 Directory.Delete(@directory, true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Directory.Delete(string.Format(@"C:\{0}\AppData\Local",Environment.UserName), true);
```

As per Alex comment, if you want to delete "C:\USERS\NAME\AppData\Local" then use this code.

```
var directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApp‌​licationData);
Directory.Delete(directory, true);
```