# How to retrieve current NTLM username from a C# Windows Service?

Tags: c#, service, ntlm

As per title, how to retrieve current `NTLM` username from a `C#` Windows Service?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c) answers question "as per title", but I strongly suspect you believe "current user" is some magical concept of "current interactive user" - one from many picked by presumably [fair random number](https://www.xkcd.com/221/) :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the Environment.UserName property what you're looking for?

[Environment.UserName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username(v=vs.110).aspx)