# How to tell the username of a signed in user in Windows (7, 8, 8.1, and 10)?

Tags: c#

I'm coding another C# application, and I was wondering how I can get the signed in user's username and C:\Users\ path. Will this method work? [How do I get the current username in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c) ? I wasn't sure because this was for Windows XP, and things update over time.

INFO: Using Windows RT where you CANNOT run EXEs without a jailbreak, and the jailbreak limits to .NET Framework 4.5.0. I can't code fast on a Core 2 Duo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's better to do the following:

```
string userName = Environment.UserName;
```

doing the other method shows the PC's domain

Comment: thanks for improving the answer. It's giving a result of the actual username instead of a domain-name/username