# How to get the users certain directory for apps

Tags: c#

I am trying to make it so it finds the current user on the pc so that when i put (for example USERPROFILE) it can find the right directory to the exe

```
        private void siticoneImageButton3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Process.Start("C:\\Users\\USERPROFILE\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\lunarclient\\Lunar Client.exe");
        }
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c) should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the Environment.UserName property like so:

```
Process.Start($"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\lunarclient\\Lunar Client.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Environment.UserName` or `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` to get the path to `(...)\AppData\Local` directory.