# Is There A Way To Access The UserID of Windows Authentication for SQL Server Express?

Tags: c#, sql-server, blazor, sql-server-express, blazor-webassembly

I am developing an internal web app using Blazor (WebAssembly) and SQL Server Express 15. The web app will only be accessed while within our network.

As I am extremely early in development, I currently host the Blazor app and the SQL server on my workstation; eventually the app and SQL server will reside on a more traditional server inside our firewall.

I'm using the default Windows Authentication for SQL Server. **What I'd like to do is, via Blazor, access the Windows userid of whoever is interacting with the SQL server by virtue of accessing the web app.** I could then use that information to (for example) show that user their weekly timesheet when they go to My Timesheet within the web app.

**Is there a way to access the Windows userid that authenticated into SQL Server?** Or am I misunderstanding things / off-base is some fashion? Or is there another way to get the Windows userid without interacting with SQL Server?

*What I've Tried*

I've tried System.Environment.UserName, but that returns "Browser". I've also tried System.Environment.UserDomainName, but that returns "localhost". I've also tried System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name and code based on ManagementObjectSearcher, but both throw an exception under WebAssembly, as WebAssembly is not Windows (even when running on a Windows server and/or a Windows browser-client).

From the other suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c), I was unable to find the right using statements or other syntax in Blazor for

- Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name,
- System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName,
- User.Identity.Name,
- System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName, and
- HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.

Answer (score -1):

check this tutorial from Medium:
https://vaibhavbhapkarblogs.medium.com/windows-authentication-authorization-in-blazor-application-144d23dd90be
should be the right starting point.

The part you need is inside the custom **AuthenticationStateProvider** you need to implement:

```
//Getting logged in windows user name
var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I tried System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name previously, and received an exception when doing so. I just now re-tried it (following the directions of your linked guide), and received "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform."

Comment: You cannot use a server side technology on client side. You need to use this call in your server (backend) side. The example from Medium is for a Blazor Server side application and it works as expected. 
If you prefer to use a Blazor WASM you need to implement a mechanism to call a server side page where you can receive the user, than you need to pass it back to client side using a cookie.
Look at Chris: https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/

Comment: The mechanism I've described is the same you can find in the template with IdentityServer authentication, where the authentication pages (login/logout/profile/etc.) are server side technology and the other parts are in WASM.

Comment: I don't want to build a login system. What I want is just to obtain the userid used by Windows Authentication; I'd then build my own list of privileges based on what userid they have (as all users will be employees of the company). I took another crack at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;, but I could only get the app to build when that property was used on the server-side. If it's used on the server-side, it only tells me what userid launched the server, not what userid has accessed the (client) website. I suspect getting client Windows userids is not possible. :-/