# Parameter value not sending Console Application after Publish app

Tags: c#, .net, console

I am working on console application (**.NetFramework 4.8 in VS2022**) for Process Some data.

I want Send parameter when execute `.exe` file from Scheduler and manually with different parameters.

its working in **VS2022 LOCAL PC** with Release and Debug Mode, **But **when I publish application and execute by double click or from scheduler parameter not passing to .exe file.

let me know if any Configuration missing or other way to Identify .exe file execute from scheduler or manually, in console Application Code.

Thanks.

I tried with VS2022 and VS2019 with .net framework 4.5 and 4.8,
also tried to identification using `Environment.CurrentDirectory` but its not working properly.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   try
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"Process Start");

       if (args.Length > 0)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"you passed argument {args[0]}"); // this argument value not working when Application Published
           if (args.Any(X => X == "manually")) {
               // execute from manually process
           }
           else {
               // execute from scheduler process
           }
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
   Console.WriteLine($"Process End");
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen or see? You probably do not pass any args when double clicking?

Comment: By "scheduler" you mean Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: BTW: It's probably not too good an idea to include a `Console.ReadKey()` when the app is planned to be used in a scheduler.

Comment: Yes, its  Windows Task Scheduler. Console.ReadKey() is use for showing output while development time @Fildor

Comment: So if you pass _no_ args ( 0 ) , then `Console.WriteLine($"you passed argument {args[0]}")` is going to throw IndexOutOfRangeException. Does it? => https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZQNjKN

Comment: If you configure the scheduler to start the App under "Service" Principal or specific User, you could use that to determine if you are running scheduled or manually. => https://stackoverflow.com/q/1240373/982149 If the scheduler runs it as current User, that won't work, of course.

Comment: @Fildor thanks a lot for helping, finally I got solution and posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution on above question
go to > Property > Publish > **Options** under the Install Mode and Settings > Select Manifest > **Checked Allow URL parameters to be Passed to application**.

[image]